# Template object property of a class

Tags: c++

I have implemented working template `class LList< T>` and now I want object of this template class to be a property of a new class called Factory2. Here is how my Factory2 class looks like

```
#include "LList.h"
template<typename T>
class Factory2
{
public:
    Factory2();
   ~Factory2();
private:
    LList<T> arr;
 };
```

I have defined the  constructor and destructor of Factory2 but how should I implement them for the `LList< T> arr` object? The `LList< T>` class has it's own constructor and destructor. I get the error:undefined reference to the constructor of `LList<int>::LList()` and `LList<int>::~LList()`

Comment: My guess is, you've implemented methods of `LList` in a separate source file. That ain't gonna work - templates must be implemented in a header. The compiler needs to see the full definition at the point where the template is actually used and its parameters become known.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik for the LList class I have defined the methods in the header file and implemented them in the LList.cpp file

Comment: Like I said, move implementations to the header.

Comment: Thanks,it worked.